# Backbone: how can I reference a Collection from a Model

Tags: backbone.js

I know it's more often done in the opposite way, but in my specific use case I'd need to have a Model ***PostsTimes*** with a reference to a Collection (of another Model ***Post***). Right now I'm trying:

```
var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Post
});
var posts = new Posts(); // my collection



var PostsTimes = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "api/times.php",
    initialize: function(options){
        this.posts = options.posts;
    },
    test: function(){
        console.log(this.posts);
    }
});

var poststimes = new PostsTimes({posts: posts});
```

But `this.posts` in `PostsTimes` always stays `undefined`. Is there any way I can do this without defining a global variable?

Comment: what is `Tampon.posts` ? some data or the other collection?

Comment: @ClaudiuHojda Sorry, that's a typo. Fixing it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of what you have is correct, so the reason it would be logging `undefined` is because the `this` in your `test` function is something other than the model's instance.

So your `PostsTimes` would become

```
var PostsTimes = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "api/times.php",
    initialize: function(options){
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.posts = options.posts;
    },
    test: function(){
        console.log(this.posts);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, no, that's the thing, the Model is not part of the Collection (I'll make the question clearer)

Comment: @julien_c Sorry I misunderstood, I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: This was it, thanks! I always forget about this gotcha... Couldn't instance methods be bound to the instance by default?

Answer (score 1):

```
var PostsTimes = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: "api/times.php",
  initialize: function(options){
    _.bindAll(this, 'test');
    this.posts = options.posts;
  },
  test: function(){
    console.log(this.posts);
  }
});
```